Looping through a search using VBA in MS Word
I’m a writer and use VBA to help me clean up my manuscript. I have an adverb search code that works. The code searches my manuscript and highlights every work ending with "ly".
My problem is that I cannot figure out how to count the number of words the code highlights.
I would appreciate your help with this.
Thanks,
Amilcar (Aumi) hernandez
Sub Adverbs()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i           As Integer
Dim cnt         As Integer
Dim color       As Integer
Dim msg         As String
Dim slist       As String
Dim title       As String
Dim hilite      As String
Dim rng         As range
Dim SearchList() As String

    '-- User assigned data ------------
    slist = "<[! ][! ]@ly>,"
    title = "Adverbs"
    color = wdBrightGreen
    hilite = "Bright-green"
    
    '-- Code assigned variables ------
    cnt = 0
    SearchList = Split(slist, ",")
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = color
    
    '-- Seach and highlight ------
    With ActiveDocument.range.Find
        .Text = SearchList(i)
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Replacement.Text = "^&"
        cnt = cnt + 1
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    
    '-- This line of code jumps to the top of the document
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    '-- Popup mesasge when the macro finishes
    msg = "The " & title & " script finished highlighting ->" & cnt & "<- words/phrases in " & hilite & "."
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation
    
End Sub



Replace:=wdReplaceAll replaces instances all at once.
Using Replace:=wdReplaceOne to replace instance one by one.

    '-- User assigned data ------------
    slist = "<[! ^13]@ly>," ' **
    title = "Adverbs"
    color = wdBrightGreen
    hilite = "Bright-green"
    
    '-- Code assigned variables ------
    cnt = 0
    SearchList = Split(slist, ",")
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = color
    
    '-- Seach and highlight ------
    i = 0 ' **
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .Text = SearchList(i)
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
'        .Replacement.Text = "^&"
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        ' **
        Do While .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne)
            cnt = cnt + 1
            .Parent.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With



If all hightlight word(s) are formated with the code in your post, below snippet can count the hightlight. It is same as the times of replacement.

Sub CountHighlight()
    Dim i As Long
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Highlight = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        Do While .Execute
            i = i + 1
            .Parent.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
    MsgBox "Found " & i & " highlight in Doc."
End Sub

